# How do I create a custom index column in PowerQuery?

Tags: powerquery

I have the following data in PowerQuery:

```
| ParentX | A |
| ParentY | A |
| ParentZ | A |
| ParentY | B |
| ParentZ | B |
| ParentX | C |
| ParentY | C |
| ParentZ | C |
```

I want to add an index column that counts the number of parents for an element:

```
| ParentX | A | 3 |
| ParentY | A | 2 |
| ParentZ | A | 1 |
| ParentY | B | 2 |
| ParentZ | B | 1 |
| ParentX | C | 3 |
| ParentY | C | 2 |
| ParentZ | C | 1 |
```

The end goal is to pivot based on this new column like this:

```
| Object | Root    | Parent 2 | Parent 3 |
| A      | ParentZ | ParentY  | ParentX  |
| B      | ParentZ | ParentY  |          |
| C      | ParentZ | ParentY  | ParentX  |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the query I used to generate the index column in the question:

```
let
    // This has the original parent/child column
    Source = #"Parent Child Query",

    // Count the number of parents per child
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Attribute:id"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), type number}}),

    // Add a new column of lists with the indexes per child
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "ParentIndex", each List.Numbers([Count], [Count], -1)),

    // Expand the lists in the previous step
    #"Expand ParentIndex" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "ParentIndex"),

    // Create the column name columns (Parent.1, Parent.2, etc)
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expand ParentIndex", "ParentColumn", each "Parent."&Text.From([ParentIndex])),

    // Adds an index column that you use when merging with the original table
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Index", 0, 1)
in
    #"Added Index"
```

Once this was done I created another query to hold the merged result:

```
let
    // This is the original parent/child column
    Source = #"Parent Child Query",

    // Add an index column that matches the index column in the previous query
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1),

    // Merge the two queries based on the index columns
    Merge = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Index",{"Index"},#"Epic Parent Indices",{"Index"},"NewColumn"),

    // Expand the new column
    #"Expand NewColumn" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Merge, "NewColumn", {"ParentColumn"}, {"ParentColumn"}),

    // Remove the index column
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expand NewColumn",{"Index"}),

    // Sort the data by attribute and then by Parent column so the columns will be in the right order
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Removed Columns",{{"Attribute:id", Order.Descending}, {"ParentColumn", Order.Ascending}}),

    // Pivot!
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Sorted Rows", List.Distinct(#"Sorted Rows"[ParentColumn]), "ParentColumn","Parent:id")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

There were three key steps here:

1. Use [Table.Group](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TableGroup-e8efd80f-47ea-40a9-ba0f-05f0ff1e67b6) to get the number of parents per child element.
2. Use [List.Numbers](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ListNumbers-4f89a4ac-acf9-4c8c-918b-36705798cc02) to get index values for each parent/child relationship.
3. Use [Table.AddIndexColumn](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TableAddIndexColumn-78d8d8ab-f9ce-4328-805b-89bf4ce945da) to add index columns to be used as the key in the call to [Table.Join](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TableJoin-b51c8463-f989-490d-aed4-a00aaed87d85) If you don't do this then you'll get duplicate data in the merge.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an Excel Table with 2 Columns (`Parents`, `Child`)
2. Use this Table in Power Query
3. Insert function `Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(";")` (See Line3)
4. Group by `Child` and use function above (See Line 4)
5. Split result (Line 5)

**The code:**

```
let
    Quelle    = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Tabelle2"]}[Content],
    fcombine  = Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(";"), 
    #"Group1" = Table.Group(Quelle, {"Child"}, {{"Parents", each fcombine([Parent]), type text}}),
    #"Split1" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Group1", "Parents", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";"),{"Parents.1", "Parents.2", "Parents.3"}),
    #"Result" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split1", {{"Parents.1", type text}, {"Parents.2", type text}, {"Parents.3", type text}})
in
    #"Result"
```

Greetings
R.

Comment: What do you mean by "`insert function Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(";")`"? I can't use `CombineTextByDelimiter` with `Group By`.

Also, will this work for an arbitrary number of parents? that's what I have -- I use a max of three in the example but my data has more.